# Codeigniter - How to inner join?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, inner-join, codeigniter-3

I want to do inner join between estate table and estatetype table. I make a edit page but I want to show customer information by cusId. I can draw data from estate table. But estateType in estate table. I hold estateType names in estatetype table. When I call estateType from estate table, just showing number(1,2,3) But I want to show their names from estatetype table. How I can do it?

I want to show customer estate information by Id from estatetype table. But I cannot do this.

Controller:

```
$viewData = new stdClass();

            $this->load->model('join_model');
            $viewData->estateList = $this->join_model->estatetypes();

            $viewData->customers = $this->db->where("cusId", $cusId)->get("customer")->row();
            $viewData->property = $this->db->where("cusId", $cusId)->get("estate")->row();
            $viewData->estype = $this->db->get("estatetype")->result();
            $viewData->heating = $this->db->get("heating")->result();
            $viewData->cities = $this->db->get("city")->result();
            $this->load->view('property_edit',$viewData);
```

Model:

```
<?php

class Join_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function estatetypes()
    {
        $this->db->select('estate.CusId,estate.estateType,estatetype.estateTypeId,estatetype.estateTypeAr,estatetype.estateTypeEng');
        $this->db->from('estate');
        $this->db->join('estatetype', 'estate.estateType = estatetype.estateTypeEng');

        $results = $this->db->get()->row();
        return $results;

        //return $this->db->get_where('users', array('userId' => $id), 1);
    }

}
```

I want to show when I add estateType from estate table in view, show estataTypeEn from estateType. For this, I did the inner join but when I add this to view and controller. There is nothing. How do I do this?

View:

```
<!-- Basic select -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Estate Type <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <select name="estateType" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="<?php echo $property->estateType; ?>" readonly><?php echo $estateList->estateType; ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach($estype as $etype){ ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $etype->estateTypeId; ?>"><?php echo $etype->estateTypeEng; ?></option>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

estatetype table (types names are here)

```
CREATE TABLE `estatetype` (
  `estateTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estateTypeNameEn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateTypeNameAr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`payTypeId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

estate table

```
 CREATE TABLE `estate` (
  `estateId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CusId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateCentare` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateRoom` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateSalon` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateBathroom` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateHeating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateCity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateAddress` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCoord` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateGarden` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estateBalcony` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `estatePackage` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `estatePackageDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estatePackageUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCreateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateCreateUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateEditDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateEditUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateDue` decimal(5,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estateImg` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`estateId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: No one can help me for this?

Comment: If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer $this->db->join('table2', table2.val = table1.val', 'inner');

Comment: Can you show me it? I cannot understand.

Comment: How do your database tables look like?

Comment: I added my database tables on top.

Comment: You r joining table based on `estate.estateType` which is `int` with `estatetype.estateTypeEng` which is `varchar` , this is wrong you have to put `estate table` id as foreign key also in `estatetype table` and then match it, u will get u desired result, Hope u will get the idea

Comment: Hmm how is it? You can show me with answer please @pradeep

Comment: setup your tables first with primary and foreign key within your tables , data can be retrieved easily then

Comment: for that add  a column in `estatetype` table which contains `estateId` of `estate` table

Comment: We can equal both of estateId=estateTypeId ?

Comment: I want to show from estateTypeNameEn from estatetype by cusId. Each customers can see them information of estate type on view. I just want to it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Join` you can create a `custom_helper.php`

A CodeIgniter helper is a PHP file with multiple functions. *It is not a class*

Create a file and put the following code into it.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('get_name'))
{
    function get_name($id,$value)
    {
        $CI=& get_instance();
        $number_data = $CI->db->get_where('estatetype', array('estateTypeId' => $id))->num_rows();
        if($number_data > 0){
            $data = $CI->db->get_where('estatetype', array('estateTypeId' => $id))->row()->$value;
        }
        else{
            $data = translate('Not_Found');
        }
        return $data;
    }   
}
```

Save this to **application/helpers/** .

## Using The Helper

---

Load this in your **controller**

```
$this->load->helper('custom_helper');
```

If you use this helper in a lot of locations you can have it load automatically by adding it to the autoload configuration file i.e. `<your-web-app>\application\config\autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom_helper');
```

And in your view, you can call this function like this.

```
<select name="estateType" class="form-control">
<?php
$estype = $this->db->get("estate")->result_array();
foreach($estype as $row){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['estateType']; ?>"><?php echo get_name($row['estateType'],'estateTypeNameEn'); ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

if you want to get other table or other columns from a table you can change the function like this.

```
function get_name($table,$field,$equal,$value)
{
    $CI=& get_instance();
    $number_data = $CI->db->get_where($table, array($field => $equal))->num_rows();
    if($number_data > 0){
        $data = $CI->db->get_where($table, array($field => $equal))->row()->$value;
    }
    else{
        $data = translate('Not_Found');
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and in view you can add this.

```
<select name="estateType" class="form-control">
<?php
$estype = $this->db->get("estate")->result_array();
foreach($estype as $row){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['estateType']; ?>"><?php echo get_name('estatetype','estateTypeId',$row['estateType'],'estateTypeNameEn'); ?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: I can see nothing. Select is blank.

Comment: I just call the names of estateType table. Just see names. Can I do this with Inner Join. I have to use Inner join, i think. Can you give an example with Inner Join?

Comment: I use this helper but I cannot see any name. estateTypeNameEn is in estatetype table. estateType is in estate table.

Comment: You must call your statetype name with this function like this `get_name('for_key','the name you want')`

Comment: There is 2 tables. One of estate table is customer's estate informations and the second one is estatetype table. estatetype has estateTypeNameEn (villa,apartment etc.). I want to get show these names in view from call estatetype table.

Comment: this is inner join sql code:

SELECT
estatetype.estateTypeId,
estatetype.estateTypeEng,
estatetype.estateTypeAr,
estate.CusId,
estate.estateType
FROM
estate
INNER JOIN estatetype ON estate.estateType = estatetype.estateTypeEng

Comment: Can we do this with inner join?

Comment: estatetype from estate table and estateTypeId from estatetype table have same value. And I want to show estateTypeNameEn in view from estatetype table.

Comment: can you give an example with InnerJoin? @AbdulAhmad Matin

Comment: Yeah I looked but I give again same error. Blank Select Box. I did this: $sql = "SELECT estate.estateType,estateType.estateTypeId,estateType.estateTypeEng,estateType.estateTypeAr FROM estatetype WHERE estate.estateType = estateType.estateTypeEng";
            $this->db->query($sql);

How show it in view?

Comment: You must send it to view and then use it.

Comment: My inner join example. `$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
$query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: $this->db->select('*'); $this->db->from('estate'); $this->db->join('estateType', 'estate.estateType = estateType.estateTypeId'); $query = $this->db->get();
            $viewData->estatetypes = $query; I did it.

View:

<option value="<?php echo $property->estateType; ?>" readonly><?php echo $estatetypes->estateType; ?></option> There is nothing. Blank. not work i'cant.

Comment: You currently using your last code .what is this ` $estatetypes->estateType` remove it and replace it with new code

Comment: I can't help more see this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Oh it gives an error. When I add second data, 2 info in same table view.1
For example I added second customer estate information but there is twice info. How I show just customer' estate Information?

 120-0001 Separate House  Residence 1520 Combi Boiler District Heating 
10 120-0001 Separate House  Residence 123 Combi Boiler District Heating

Separate House Residence this repeat. Separate House is first customer estate info, Residence is second same customer estate info belong same cusId. I want to show no repeat it same column in table view.

Comment: I dont understand :function get_name($table,$field,$equal,$value)
{
    $CI=& get_instance();
    $number_data = $CI->db->get_where($table, array($field => $equal))->num_rows();
    if($number_data > 0){
        $data = $CI->db->get_where($table, array($field => $equal))->row()->$value;
    }
    else{
        $data = translate('Not_Found');
    }
    return $data;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174585/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-khaoscrea).

Comment: Can u see my last question post? @AbdulAhmad Matin?